# ActiveRecord get all models with a specific set of related models (AND not OR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a database of cars, and these cars have specific features (like seat heating, LED lights, AC, ...).

The models are set up like this:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :car_key_features
  has_many :key_features, through: :car_key_features
end

class CarKeyFeature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :key_feature
end

class KeyFeature < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :car_key_features
  has_many :cars, through: :car_key_features
end
```

I now want to get all cars that have a specific set of features. For example, I want to get all cars that have features with the identifiers "seat-heating" AND "led-lights" (but it could also have additional features).

I tried it with the following query, but this gives me all cars that have at least one of the features, not all of them (as it results in a SQL "IN" query):

```
scope :by_key_features, ->(identifiers) { joins(:key_features).where(key_features: { identifier: identifiers }).group('cars.id') }
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will select all cars that have at least one matching feature. Therefore you need to select only cars which have the same number of all features as there are in the query.

```
scope :by_key_features, ->(identifiers) {
  joins(:key_features)
    .where(key_features: { identifier: identifiers })
    .group('cars.id')
    .having('COUNT(key_features.id) >= ?', identifiers.size) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this doesn't exactly do what I want. If I query for "seat-heating" and "led-lights", this would also return the cars that have one of these features in addition to another one, like "air-conditioning".

Comment: That should not happen because this query would first filter only matching rows (the `where` part), group them and then only return cars that have at least the same number of rows in the result set as there where conditions (the `having` part). This query will return cars that have even more features (the `>=` part), but not cars with  fewer features. Did you actually _test_ that behavior or do you only _think_ it might have that behavior?

Comment: I am very sorry, this is indeed doing exactly what I want! Thank you very much!